# How to handle 'simplexml_load_string' error?

Tags: php, xml

I am looking to handle a situation whereby the XML file that I at trying to retrieve is not ready or is not available.

I am using:

```
 $object = simplexml_load_string($file);
```

Sometimes, I get the following error:

```
'Start tag expected, '<' not found in etc...'
```

I have tried the following, and it doesn't work.

```
 if($object === false){
 // code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simplexml_load_string can return false if there is an error. It can also emit a warning.

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php):

> Returns an object of class SimpleXMLElement with properties containing the data held within the xml document, or FALSE on failure.
>
> Produces an E_WARNING error message for each error found in the XML data.
>
> Use libxml_use_internal_errors() to suppress all XML errors, and libxml_get_errors() to iterate over them afterwards.

```
// suppress warnings so we can handle them ourselves
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$object = simplexml_load_string($file);

if ($object === false) {
    // oh no
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    // do something with them
    print_r($errors);
    // really you'll want to loop over them and handle them as necessary for your needs
}
```

More detail on [`libxml_get_errors` here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php).

Comment: Implementing what you suggested I nevertheless get 'Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in....' - is this something i need to turn off in the php.innit file?

Comment: My bad, it needs to be passed with `true` as an option! Feels like the default should be true rather than false, considering the name "use internal errors".